# Google Calendar API event update always return 404 “not found” error

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am trying to update a google calendar event using full calendar. I successfully inserted an event in google calendar using full calendar. While updating I am getting 404 not found code below is the sample of error

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Following the example at Google Reference (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#php) I am trying to update google calendar event from Full Calendar. Here what I am doing

```
//I am getting eventid from my db and all other values from the form
function edit_event_gcal(title,color,id) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Calendar.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {"title":title, "color":color, "task": "editCalendar", "eventid": id},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Data",data)
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my Calendar.php

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; //php library for google calendar
$sTask = (isset($_POST['task']) && !empty($_POST['task'])) ? $_POST['task'] : '';
$sTitle = (isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title'])) ? $_POST['title'] : '';
$sColor = (isset($_POST['color']) && !empty($_POST['color'])) ? $_POST['color'] : '';
$sEventId = (isset($_POST['eventid']) && !empty($_POST['eventid'])) ? $_POST['eventid'] : '';

function getClient()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);
        $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

        $tokenPath = 'token.json';
        if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        }
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            } else {
                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';
                $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }
            // Save the token to a file.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
        return $client;
    }

    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $calendarId = 'mygooglecalendarid';
    if($sTask == "editCalendar")
    {
        $event = $service->events->get('primary', $sEventId);

        $event->setSummary('Appointment at Somewhere');

       $updatedEvent = $service->events->update($calendarId, $event->getId(), $event);

       //Print the updated date.
       echo $updatedEvent->getUpdated();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am using same configuration for inserting.
Looking for Positive response. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### `$service->events->get` expects the calendar id and event id as parameters

It is important to double-check that both parameters are correct

- If `'mygooglecalendarid'` is not your `primary` calendar, then you are trying to get the event from one calendar and update it into a different one - this will give you a 404 error (bad request).
- If the eventid is not correct, this will also lead to a 404 error.
  The latter can be verified by using the [Try This API feature for Events:get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)
- Possible ways to retrieve the correct event id are either [listing events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) or retrieve the `calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/...` url and build the event id through decoding.

Comment: No sir this is the not problem. I am giving the right calendar id as I wrote insertion is working its just the update

Comment: But you define `$event = $service->events->get('primary', $sEventId);` instead of `$event = $service->events->get('mygooglecalendarid', $sEventId);` - is `mygooglecalendarid`your primary calendar id?

Comment: primary by default select the logged in calendar so its not the worry sir. I tried to put my claendar id also here but still same error

Comment: Are you sure then that the `eventid from my db` is the valid Calendar API Id for this event? Check it with the [Try this API for Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)

Comment: Sir. I tried here also but the same error is occurring also here. When I was testing the api here https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get  i copied the event id from my google calendar still the same error. Its very strange

Comment: What do you mean by `copied the event id from my google calendar `? If you got an error with the Try this API, it means that an event with the given Id in the given calendar does not exist. I suggest you to [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) all your events and their Ids to retrieve valid Ids.

Comment: I mean sir you can copy the event id from google calendar also by clicking the event and in the url you will see your event id

Comment: Thank you for correcting me as I am inserting the wrong id. Actually its the right id but I need to decode that id which I was not doing earlier.

Comment: If you take the id from the url `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/Nm1rYjVw...` - unfortunately this is the wrong one. I am glad that you found the error source.

Comment: No the id from the url https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/Nm1rYjVw... is right one its just that I was not decoding it

Comment: Thank you again sir. Without your help I think I was not able to track the error source

Comment: I am glad, I will update my answer for completion sake.