# Google calendar API get to update keep on giving 404

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to get the calendar event so I can then update it as the document [shows](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update).

My assumption was that an event with such JSON:

```
{
    'kind': 'calendar#event',
    'etag': '"32...000"',
    'id': '6oo....jsa',
    'status': 'confirmed',
    'htmlLink': 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=Nm...YjhAZw',
    'created': '2021-02-25T20:13:18.000Z',
    'updated': '2021-02-28T01:21:43.762Z',
    'summary': 'code',
    'creator': {
        'email': 'example@gmail.com'
    },
    'organizer': {
        'email': 'abc@group.calendar.google.com',
        'displayName': 'Website',
        'self': True
    },
    'start': {
        'dateTime': '2021-02-27T23:30:00-05:00'
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': '2021-02-28T00:00:00-05:00'
    },
    'iCalUID': 'xyz@google.com',
    'sequence': 27,
    'reminders': {
        'useDefault': True
    },
    'eventType': 'default'
}
```

The calendarId would be `iCalUID` & the eventId would be `id` or even the id after the calendar url. However, trying both of those interchangeably from the google API platform keeps on giving:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

What should I do different?

My ultimate goal is to modify the event's `summary`, startTime & endTime for any event with a calendarID and eventID, hence my code:

```
def modifying():
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        **flask.session['credentials']) 
    flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    event = {
    'summary': 'modified',
    'location': '',
    'description': '',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': '2021-02-27T17:09:25.993663-05:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles', 
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': '2021-02-27T21:09:25.993663-05:00', 
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles', 
        }
    }
    try:
        events_result =service.calendarList().list().execute()
        events = events_result.get('items', [])           
        Ids = [item['id'] for item in events] #do this so it can search across all calendars & not just 'primary'
        service.events().update(calendarId=Ids, eventId='6oo....jsa', body=event).execute()
        return 200
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        return {"message":"Server under maintenance"}
```

P.S: I have already tried all the solutions in the SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61660705/google-calendar-api-event-update-always-return-404-not-found-error) as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you are doing a [calendarlist.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)

```
events_result =service.calendarList().list().execute()
```

Which `Returns the calendars on the user's calendar list.`

The response from that being a list of calendar resources

[image]

You then appear to be trying to update a static event id '6oo....jsa' on the first calendar that is returned by the calendar list response.

```
 service.events().update(calendarId=Ids, eventId='6oo....jsa', body=event).execute()
```

How exactly do you know that this static event id is even part of that calendar?  Which is why you are getting a 404 it does not exist.

Why not do a events.list in order to get a list of the events on the calendar.  Or even better if you don't mind getting an error just do a event.get on the calendar for your static event id.

BTW event.list wont return a calendar id in the response as its assumed that you already know the calendar id since you used it go get the events in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @DalmTo! As a starter, you're 100% right that it checks only the first calendar & not all the calendar (loop), my apology for misjudgment. Now the reason I was confident that it's from the right calendar & the right event is because I have built a complex algorithm that returns back the "current" calendar event of the user (in JSON) across all the calendars which works perfectly as the name & time matches. Therefore, I thought I should just use the JSON's 'id' as eventID after "etag" and iCalUID as the calendar ID? or even use them interchangeably?

Comment: you understand that calendarlist is just a ui thing not all calendars the user has access to are there they have to be added manually by the user.

Comment: calendarlist.list will return a calendar Id which you must then do a events.list to find the event ids to use for event.update.    iCalUID can't be used in this manner

Comment: "the user has access to are there they have to be added manually by the user" Could you elaborate on what you mean here? I've worked with calendar API for a couple of months as of now & never had trouble of not being able to retrieve a specific calendar of the user.

Comment: Ohh i see what you're saying. Yeah you're right iCalUID isn't the same as CalendarID generated from calendar list.

Comment: My only question is that is there a better identifier then the calendar "summary" or "displayName" for evenList()? as name isn't the best identifier due to risk of duplication & at the same time all the ids are different for the same event in CalendarList() and eventList() of the same event

Comment: Not sure I understand a calendar will have more than one event.   I always identify them but the calendar id as the name can be updated by the user when ever they like

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

To [update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) an event with Python you need to use the method `update` of the calendar service:

```
service.events().update(calendarId=calendarId, eventId=eventId, body=body).execute()
```

The `request body` must contain the `start` and `end` dates of the event.

### How to update an event having the summary

1. [List](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) all the events on a specific calendar (`primary` for the default calendar)
2. Check the `summary` of all the events until you find one that matches your search
3. Keep the `id`, `start` and `end` dates

```
summarySearch = 'old summary'
events = service.events().list(calendarId=calendarId).execute()
for ev in events['items']:
   try:
       print(ev['summary'])
       if ev['summary'] == summarySearch:
           eventId = ev['id']
           startDate = ev['start']['date']
           endDate = ev['end']['date']
   except:
       print('empty summary')
```

4. Define the new summary (and all the fields to update)
5. Define the `body request`. It can be easily constructed with [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update?apix=true)
6. [Update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) the event

```
#startDate = '2021-02-16' # uncomment to overwrite
#endDate = '2021-02-18'   # uncomment to overwrite
summary = 'new summary'
 
body = {
   'start': {'date': startDate},
   'end': {'date': endDate},
   'summary': summary
}
 
result = service.events().update(calendarId=calendarId, eventId=eventId, body=body).execute()
```

7. Print the `result` to check that the event has been updated successfully

### Some notes

I keep the `start` and `end` dates because they are mandatory to [update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) an event. If you want to overwrite them is okay and you don't have to store them previously, but I wanted to give a solution that can fit in more situations.

### Reference

- [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update)
- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)